# Jquery Cloning and Update Button Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I am overlooking something really simple here. I need another set of eyes. I've spent much more time on this than I should.

Take a look at this fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/R8SxU/

Why won't the Icon Update after adding more than one year?
I want the top one to always be a plus to symbolize adding a new year, and the remaining ones below to be a minus to remove. It works on the first one, but only the first one. I believe I have the correct selector as the function (console out) is activated correctly with each button.

### HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="year-0">Enter Year</label>
    <input id="year-0" type="number" title="Enter Year"/>
    <button id="addYear" title="Add Year">Year</button>
</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$('#addYear')
    .button({icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus' } })
    .on('click', function() { 
        var clone      = $('div').first().clone(true),
            peroid     = $('div').length;

        //update ID
        $(clone).find('label').prop('for','year-' + peroid);
        $(clone).find('input').prop('id','year-' + peroid);

        $('div:first button')
            .prop('id','')
            .attr('title','Remove Year')
            .addClass('removeYear');


        $(clone).insertBefore('div:first');
        $('.removeYear:first')
             .off('click')
             .button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-circle-minus' } })  // Why Wont This Work
             .on('click', function() { console.log('remove function');  });

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by why won't it update?

Comment: @j08691 look at the fiddle for the clear demonstration. You Hit the Button, It adds another input/label/button combo. The icon on the last button changes from a plus to a minus (to remove). This works the first time, but any subsequent times it simply stays a plus.

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the problem or not, but you should be using attr() instead of prop()  (except for accessing an element's ID where I believe the two are interchangeable).

Comment: @MattB. Thanks Matt! I always love improving my code. But you are right, this is not relevant to my problem.

Comment: Do you want the top one to always be a plus icon and all others to be minus icons?

Comment: I would output  $('.removeYear:first').length to the console to make sure it's in fact returning an element after the second click of the addYear button.

Comment: @RubenInfante Yes, that is precisely what I want. I apologize if that was not clear.

Comment: @MattB. I have, and It is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y33GV/

Comment: @undefined this would satisfy my requirements on listing each chunk in a logical way. You should consider submitting this answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#addYear').button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus'
    }
}).on('click', function () {
    var clone = $(this).parent().clone(),
        peroid = $('div').length;

    clone.find('label').prop('for', 'year-' + peroid).end()
         .find('input').prop('id', 'year-' + peroid).end()
         .find('button').prop('id', 'id' + peroid).prop('title', 'Remove Year')
         .addClass('removeYear').find('span:first').addClass('ui-icon-circle-minus');

    clone.insertAfter('div:last');
});

$(document).on('click', 'div:not(":first") button', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y33GV/

Comment: you even wrote the remove function for me! how kind. I dislike this method of directly targeting the span and adding the desired class, I *feel* like this should be done with `.button`, but I cannot argue with what works. +1 Thanks!

Comment: @matchew You are welcome, sorry, honestly I haven't used `button` method so far, but I think adding a class is more efficient than calling a method.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out:-http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/R8SxU/4/

```
var clone = $('div').last().clone(true),
         peroid = $('div').length;
```

instead of

```
var clone=$('div').first().clone(true),
            peroid=$('div').length;
```

Comment: This almost works, but it **fails** to preserve the logical order. Notice if would If I clicked the button 3 times and had four years I would expect the ids to be as followed: id-3,id-2,id-1,id-4. Your answer would return id-1,id-3,id-2,id-0. This would be confusing to a user and therefore I would consider it undesirable. I am sorry I cannot accept this answer, but I will give you a +1.